# How to delete rows that contain certain numbers

Tags: r

I'm working on a table that contains a lot of NAs and answers by numbering
and it looks like this

```
structure(list(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110), a = c(NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, 10, 9, 9, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA,NA), c = c(NA, NA, NA, 9, 1, NA, NA, 4, 11, 9), d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 7, 9, 9), e = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, 8, NA, 9), f = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), g = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And what I am trying to do is delete rows that only contains number 9.
In this case ID 103, 104, 110 would be the case. I want those 3 rows to be removed.

I tried the code below

```
df1[rowSums(df1[-1]==9)==0,]
```

But, with having NAs in the table, it only reproduces NA table.
Please help :( !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to check for the whole row:

```
df1[apply(df1[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(na.omit(x) == 9) | all(is.na(x))), ]

#    ID  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
# 1 101 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 2 102  9 10 NA NA NA NA NA
# 5 105 NA NA  1  8  9 NA NA
# 6 106 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 7 107 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA
# 8 108 NA NA  4  7  8 NA  9
# 9 109 NA NA 11  9 NA NA NA
```

I use `na.omit` to get rid of the `NA`-values in each row and then check if all the remaining values are equal to 9.

Comment: Wow! this is what i wanted! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `na.rm` argument to ignore the NAs:

```
df1[rowSums(df1[-1]==9, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
```

But also note that this code will only keep the rows that don't have *any* 9, which isn't exactly what you are asking for in the question.

---

edit after comment:

in that case simply flip:

```
df1[rowSums(df1[-1]!=9, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as I said, I want to delete rows that only have 9.  The result of code shows ID 101, 106 and 107 which don't have any 9, but to add that I want to delete rows that have number 9 + other numbers (such as ID 105, 108, 109).

Comment: Though it deletes all NAs rows altogether, it works! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a much more efficient way, but the following works, I believe:

```
df1[!(apply(df1[-1] == 9, 1, prod, na.rm = TRUE) * !apply(is.na(df1[-1]), 1, prod)), ]
```